# Protractor: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver

Tags: internet-explorer, webdriver, protractor

I have a problem running automated tests for IE. When I'm trying to start my tests using the command: `protractor myConfig.js` I'm getting the following error:

```
> UnknownError: The path to the driver executable must be set by the
> webdriver.ie. driver system property
```

I already copied the IEDriver manually but I don't know how to change the webdriver.ie.driver path.

Answer (score 4):

Try to install and/or update protractors internet explorer manager with command

```
webdriver-manager update --ie
```

Then restart protractor and it should work!